# What does build action cause new check-outs on in a project solution

Tags: .net, tfs, build, visual-studio-2005, vcs-checkout

There is something in VS 2005 causing the new check-outs in another solutions of project file. Imagine There are 20 solutions in a Project of VS 2005 (.net 2.0 and c# )

Project names are: A , B , C ... S, T,

A has some references from B or S...

And when I build the solution A, it starts to check-out on me some of files from different solutions ( it may be a solution file or project file..)

It did not use to happen two days ago.. It was normal only the files that I change are check-out to me. not others.

Where should I go and check to make it the same as it use to build perfectly on TFS?

[image: I click build and it immediately starts check-out. Why?!]

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify it is just your working environment that is having the issue?  I have ran into many times when VS will force me to checkout files without my wanting it to happen.  In almost every case it ended up being that one developer installed a SP and updated the project files while all other developers were on a different SP.

Another option you have here is to turn off this automatic checkout feature [here is a walkthrough](http://www.woodwardweb.com/teamprise/disabling_tfs_a.html)

Granted, that may not be an ideal solution but it will resolve the problem short-term.  I would do a compare on the project files to see what is being changed.

Hopefully these ideas will help you avoid the frown face.